# Optimize Excel Macro - Speed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There are two worksheets named Data and Calc.

The Data tab has app 200,000 rows and 14 columns. Each month going forward I will be adding roughly 1500 rows of data.

Calc tab fetches the relevant data from the data tab.

Cell K3:HB3 are numbers from 1 to 200.

Below is the formula which is used to calculate data for 1500 rows and 200 columns and currently I am taking roughly 15 mins to do the calculations.

Please could you help me in processing the below macro faster.

```
Sub Calc()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Dim S As Workbook
Dim j, 1stcolm as Integer
Dim S1, D1 As Worksheet

Set S1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“Data”)
Set D1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“Calc”)
Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = “=SUMIFS(Data!C2,DATE(YEAR(‘Calc’!R[0]C5),MONTH(‘Calc’R[0]C5)+’Calc’!R3C[0]-1,1),Data!C7,’Calc’!R[0]C2)”

D1.Activate

For j = 4 To D1.Range(“B” & Rows.Count). End (3) (1). Row

        Range(“K” & j, “HB” & j) = myFormula
        Next j

Application.Screenupdating= True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code is functional, and speed is the only issue, then your question belongs in Code Review instead.

Comment: Load everything into variant arrays and loop them and loop them putting the output in another variant array.  Then mass put the output as one.

Comment: Posted code should be very fast, since it doesn't actually do anything ?

Comment: I edited. my above code. with the formula can you check and let me know how it looks now

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the automatic calculation and reactivate it at the end of your code. Also, it is better to not use a formula in your code, prefer the use of the loop.

```
Sub OptimizeTimeCode() 

    'Remove the update of Excel screen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Remove pop-up
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    'Remove the automatic calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    '... your code
 
   'To be re-activated at the end of the process
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited. my above code. with the formula can you check and let me know how it looks now